# How can I stop a function from updating an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, variables, recursion

The function below updates the value of an array each time it is called:

```py
import numpy as np

def disc(vectors, i, ptr, total):
    if ptr[i] < 0:
        return total
    else:
        total+=vectors[i]
        return disc(vectors, ptr[i],ptr,total)

testvec=np.array([[0,0],[1,0],[0,0],[0,0],[1,-1],[0,-1],[1,-1],[0,-1],[0,0]])
ptr=np.array([-10,2,-6,-10,2,2,4,4,-10])
t=np.array([0,0])
print(disc(testvec,7,ptr,t))
print(t)
print(disc(testvec,1,ptr,t))
```

I.e. after being called the array t has its value updated. Is it possible to reset t to [0,0] within the function or not have the value change at all?

For context I am implementing a wrapping algorithm for percolation. The function sums vectors over a tree see https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0101295.pdf for more details.

Comment: But that would break the function? t is an accumulator, basically the output of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your specific case, if you do not want the variable to be modified, you can just not modify it:

```
def disc(vectors, i, ptr, total):
    if ptr[i] < 0:
        return total
    else:
        return disc(vectors, ptr[i],ptr,total+vectors[i])
```

More in general you can wrap the arguments of a function in `copy.deepcopy` to make sure that only a copy is passed and the original variable is not modified.